# RStudio missing red x's that indicate a missing parantheses

Tags: rstudio

The little red x's that appear next to the code lines to indicate there is a missing paranthesis/bracket/character are gone. I rely on these little guys especially during nested if/else functions, and I can't figure out why they've disappeared or how to recover them. I have the latest version of RStudio (2023.12.0) installed and the latest version of R (4.3.2). Has anyone else had this issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issue! Go to Tools > Global Options > Code > Diagnostics, and check all the available boxes under "Diagnostics".